# Is it possible to have two connection strings and switch between them for each user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm creating an web application, to manage some people debt, and i need the application to be able to change the DB connection without change it for everyone.
 I try system reflection, but it changed the connection string for everybody not only for a single user.

Is it possible? if so, can someone explain me the logic behind so i can try it?

SAMPLE:

```
  var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[2];  

        var fi = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField(
                      "_bReadOnly",
                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        fi.SetValue(settings, false);

        var settingsTWO = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[3];

        var fiTWO = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField(
                      "_bReadOnly",
                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        fiTWO.SetValue(settingsTWO, false);


        try {

            if (e.Value != "NoValue") { 
                settings.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[4].ToString().Replace("DEFAULTPORTFOLIO", "AJW_"+e.Value.ToUpper()); 
                settingsTWO.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[5].ToString().Replace("DEFAULTPORTFOLIO", "AJW_" + e.Value.ToUpper()); 
                LoginButton1.Enabled = true;


                HttpCookie currentUserCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["currentUser"];
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("currentUser");
                currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
                currentUserCookie.Value = null;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie);

            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }


        try {


        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        ConnectionStringsSection sec = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        sec.ConnectionStrings["AJW2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[4].ToString().Replace("DEFAULTPORTFOLIO", "AJW_" + e.Value.ToUpper());
        sec.ConnectionStrings["AJW2Entities"].ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[5].ToString().Replace("DEFAULTPORTFOLIO", "AJW_" + e.Value.ToUpper());
        config.Save();



            switch (e.Value)
            {
                case "GAIA":
                   var config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/Web.config");
                    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
                    break;
                case "GUINCHO":
                    var config1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/Web-GUINCHO.config");
                    config1.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
                    break;
                case "OITANTE":
                    var config2 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/Web-OITANTE.config");
                    config2.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
                    break;

            }


            LoginButton1.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            LoginButton1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by some users ?

Comment: Some lawyers need to use one DB, to reach one portfolio and other lawyers need to use another one, to reach a different portfolio, same structure but different DBs, sorry my english

Comment: I have  a web application for each portfolio, the application are exactly the same, the only change is the connection string, and i want to make a single application to access all portfolios

Comment: are the users (lawyers) in Sessions or are you talking about role in asp.net

Comment: I'd say that you can provide some fake code to help you without that it will be hard to guess what you want to do or where you have your issue.

Comment: I uploaded right now :D

Answer (score 1):

In web application it is totally possible. I don't know all your implementation details but usually DB connection or any kind of DB context is instantiated per http request (it should not be shared between requests).

I don't know if you use Entity Framework or pure ADO.NET classes but when you get the request from browser you can tell what Role that user has and based on that you can initialise your DB context with connection string dynamicaly

Comment: I use Entity freamework, but everytime i try to change the DB Connection, the XML file on the server changes to everybody,  should i save it in cookies with integrated security?

Comment: You should have two connection strings
```
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="Connection1" connectionString="... " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
       <add name="Connection2" connectionString="... " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```
then when you instantiate `DBContext` you can provide name of that connection string as a parameter `new MyDBContext("Connection1");`

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate your help mate

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ADO.NET? You can create the connections on the fly, but I suggest that's not a really good approach.

With ADO.NET:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = GetConnectionStringForUser(user);
    ...
}
```

As you have two different connections, you may wrap your DB connection to an interface and resolve it one way or the other according to the user role or whatever it makes to use one or the other.

Comment: I use Entity freamework, but everytime i try to change the DB Connection, the XML file on the server changes to everybody, should i save it in cookies with integrated security?

Comment: If you are using EF, then you shouldn't swap DB Connection but having 2 different DBContext and using one or the other by being resolved by the user properties.

Comment: OK then, i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

There is very likely multiple way of doing it.

First I assume that you have some kind of user authentication which allows you to know who is calling your service.

You can follow this guide if needed [User claims](https://dev.to/rickab10/authenticate-authorization-and-claim-all-you-need-to-know-in-aspnet-core-ahn)

Then you can get information about your user like this:

```
    [HttpPost("foo/{bar}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(string bar)
    {
        var user = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;//use whatever kind of claim type you want.
        return this.ReturnIfOk(await DoSomeWork());
    }
```

Then you can switch context based on user by using a service that you would have injected in your Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IDBChooser dbChooser;

    public MyController(IDBChooser dbChooser)
    {
        this.dbChooser = dbChooser;
    }
}

//In startup 
services.AddSingleton<IDBChooser, MyDbChooser>();
```

Last but not least in your api:

```
    [HttpPost("foo/{bar}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(string bar)
    {
        var user = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;//use whatever kind of claim type you want.
       var db = this.dbChooser.GetDbForUser(user);
        return this.ReturnIfOk(await DoSomeWork(db));
    }
```

I did not write the DbChooser class as it is subject to your own logic but it's roughly giving a different context based on your input.

Comment: Thanks for that, its seems something i can explore to make what i want. Thank you

Comment: Now that I can see your code, I can add that you can do exactly the same thing using cookies. just replace `User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;` part in the api by `Request.Cookies["currentUser"]` as you did in your code.